# Adjust jQuery word counter to count URLs as 3 words

Tags: javascript, jquery, counter

I am using a counter plugin for jquery (http://wplayground.comuv.com/counter/) and have it implemented successfully in our page.  But I need to make an adjustment to it and I'm not sure where it should go.

Basically, the script counts characters (or words, in our case) and stops input when the user has reached the goal.  This part is working fine.  Now, though, I need to make an adjustment so that if a user enters a URL like example.com, that word is counted as 3 words instead of 1.  On a previous incarnation of our website, the developer wrote custom javascript to accomplish the task, and to account for the URL thing, he made the following change:

```
 if(getWord.indexOf(".com")>=1 || getWord.indexOf(".net")>=1 || getWord.indexOf(".org")>=1 || getWord.indexOf(".biz")>=1 || getWord.indexOf(".gov")>=1 || getWord.indexOf(".edu")>=1 || getWord.indexOf(".mobi")>=1 || getWord.indexOf(".info")>=1 || getWord.indexOf(".ca")>=1 || getWord.indexOf(".us")>=1 || getWord.indexOf(".mil")>=1){///Email
    pk1 = pk1+3;
```

So, following is the new jquery counter.  How would I adjust it to do the same thing?

```
/*
   jQuery (character and word) counter
   Copyright (C) 2009  Wilkins Fernandez

   This program is free software: you can redistribute it and/or modify
   it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
   the Free Software Foundation, either version 3 of the License, or
   (at your option) any later version.

   This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
   but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
   MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
   GNU General Public License for more details.

   You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
   along with this program.  If not, see <http://www.gnu.org/licenses/>.
*/
(function($) {
    $.fn.extend({
        counter: function(options) {
            // Set the default values, use comma to separate the settings
            var defaults = {
                type: 'char',   // {char || word}
                count: 'down',  // count {up || down} from or to the goal number
                goal: 140       // count {to || from} this number                
            };
            var options = $.extend({}, defaults, options);
            var flag = false;   // Set to true when goal is reached

            // Loop through each instance of the object that being is passed (the users selector).
            // Allows for multiple instances of the jQuery methods available to THIS (instance of the) object
            // (you can use this plug-in more than once on a page).
            return this.each(function() {
                var msg;
                var $obj = $(this);

                // Sets the appropriate message based on the options
                function get_msg_equation(objLength) {
                    // Make sure that the right values are set
                    if (typeof options.type !== 'string') {
                    } else {
                        switch (options.type) {
                            case 'char':
                                if (options.count === 'down') {
                                    msg = " character(s) left";
                                    return (options.goal - objLength);
                                }
                                else if (options.count === 'up') {
                                    msg = " characters (" + options.goal + " max)";
                                    return objLength;
                                }
                                break;
                            case 'word':
                                if (options.count === 'down') {
                                    msg = " word(s) left";
                                    return (options.goal - objLength);
                                }
                                else if (options.count === 'up') {
                                    msg = " words (" + options.goal + " max)";
                                    return objLength;
                                }
                                break;
                            default:
                        } //END switch
                    } // END if
                } // END function

                // * Initialize *: the bind event needs an object to bind to
                $('<div id=\"' + this.id + '_counter\"><span>' + get_msg_equation($($obj).val().length ) + '</span>' + msg + '</div>').insertAfter($obj);

                // Cache the counter selector
                var $currentCount = $("#" + this.id + "_counter" + " span");

                // Bind events to a function that returns the length
                // of the characters || words in the given text field.
                $obj.bind('keyup click blur focus change paste', function(new_length) {
                    // Update characters depending on the option selected
                    switch (options.type) {
                        case 'char':
                            new_length = $($obj).val().length;
                            break;
                        case 'word':
                            if ($obj.val() === '') {
                                new_length = 0;
                            }
                            else {
                                new_length = $.trim($obj.val())
                                    .replace(/\s+/g, " ")
                                    .split(' ').length;
                            }
                            break;
                        default:
                    } // END switch

                    // Set flag TRUE when counter reaches goal
                    switch (options.count) {
                        case 'up':
                            if (get_msg_equation(new_length) >= options.goal && options.type === 'char') {
                                $(this).val($(this).val().substring(0, options.goal));
                                flag = true;
                                break;
                            }
                            if (get_msg_equation(new_length) === options.goal && options.type === 'word') {
                                flag = true;
                                break;
                            } else if (get_msg_equation(new_length) > options.goal && options.type === 'word') {
                                $(this).val("");
                                $currentCount.text("0");
                                flag = true;
                                break;
                            }
                            break;
                        case 'down':
                            if (get_msg_equation(new_length) <= 0 && options.type === 'char') {
                                $(this).val($(this).val().substring(0, options.goal));
                                flag = true;
                                break;
                            }
                            if (get_msg_equation(new_length) === 0 && options.type === 'word') {
                                flag = true;
                            } else if (get_msg_equation(new_length) < 0 && options.type === 'word') {
                                $(this).val("");
                                flag = true;
                                break;
                            }
                            break;
                        default:
                    } // END switch

                    // Listen on keydown to catch the last character or word typed
                    // and prevent the user from typing
                    $obj.keydown(function(event) {
                        if (flag) {
                            this.focus();
                            // Listen for delete & backspace
                            if ((event.keyCode !== 46 && event.keyCode !== 8)) {
                                if ($(this).val().length > options.goal && options.type === 'char') {
                                    $(this).val($(this).val().substring(0, options.goal));
                                    return false;   // Stop the default action (typing)
                                    // Listen for blank (spacebar) & return 
                                } else if (event.keyCode !== 32 && event.keyCode !== 8 && options.type === 'word') {   //Allow to continue typing last word
                                    return true;
                                } else {
                                    return false;   // Stop the default action (typing)
                                }
                            } else {
                                flag = false;
                                return true;
                            }
                        }
                    }); // END keydown
                    $currentCount.text(get_msg_equation(new_length));
                }); // END Bind
            }); //END return
        } // END counter function
    }); // END extend
}) // END function
(jQuery); // Return jQuery object
```

Comment: Why would `example.com` be 3 words?

Comment: If you really must know, it is because the company must charge the user per word.  And the company pays per word, as well.  And when the company pays their publisher, the publisher counts URLs as 3 words.  Therefore, when allowing users to input their text, we must count a URL as 3 words.   Simple.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the middle of the counter plugin file, there is a line that looks like this:

```
else{
  new_length = $.trim($obj.val())
    .replace(/\s+/g, " ")
    .split(' ').length;
}
```

It seems like this is where it counts the words.  It's grabbing the text in the box, splitting on spaces, then counting the elements.

You could add some sort of check (regex) for URLs here, and then increment `new_length` accordingly.

Something like this (untested):

```
else{
  var str = $.trim($obj.val())
    .replace(/\s+/g, " ");
  new_length = str.split(' ').length;
  var URLs = str
    .match(/([^\s])+\.(com|net|org|biz|gov|edu|mobi|info|ca|us|mil)/g);
  if(URLs != null && URLs.length > 0){
    new_length += (URLs.length*2);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help here.  I had found that section of code but couldn't make it do what I wanted (I'm a completely newcomer to jquery and JS in general).  I implemented your fix, but am getting the following in firebug: "Cannot read property 'length' of null"

Comment: @Kevin: Yeah, I didn't test this at all. Let me fix that.